# Word VBA macro only works in debug mode

Tags: vba, debugging, replace, ms-word

My macro is supposed to do the following:

1. Look for instances of double spaces.
2. Replace those instances of double spaces with single spaces.
3. Go through the document again to see if there are any more double spaces and to replace them, if there are. For instance, if there were originally 4 spaces in a row somewhere, there will still be double spaces, so, replace remaining double spaces with single spaces.
4. Repeat the previous step until there are no more double spaces.

The problem is that the macro works perfectly in debug mode but only runs one pass if run normally. What am I doing wrong? Please note that my code may not be the most compact, but that's not the point; what I'm really wondering is why the code only works in debug mode and not in normal run mode, and how this can be fixed.

```
Sub Test_for_doubles()
'
' Test_for_doubles Macro
'
Dim blnFoundDoubles As Boolean
blnFoundDoubles = True
Do While blnFoundDoubles = True
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory 'Go to the beginning of the document.
    blnFoundDoubles = False 'Don't go through this loop again unless we find a double this time through
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "  "
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        If .Found = True Then
            blnFoundDoubles = True
        End If
    End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: @CindyMeister: Your suggestion worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always found that testing the `Found` property is a bit hit-and-miss: sometimes it works, sometimes not. I prefer to declare a Boolean variable and assign it to `Find.Execute` since the method returns True if the find is successful, otherwise False.

The code you show has another problem: it's testing `Found` before the Find is executed. Try changing your code to something more like this:

```
Dim blnFoundDoubles As Boolean
Dim bFound as Boolean
blnFoundDoubles = True
bFound = False
Do While blnFoundDoubles = True
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory 'Go to the beginning of the document.
    blnFoundDoubles = False 'Don't go through this loop again unless we find a double this time through
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "  "
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        bFound = .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceAll)
        If bFound Then
            blnFoundDoubles = True
        End If
        'OR
        'blnFoundDoubles = bFound
    End With
Loop
```

Comment: I did some additional testing with your code and my original code, and I determined that directly testing the .Found method wasn't the problem. Instead, as you said later, the problem was that I tested .Found before performing .Execute. Just figured you might want to know. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) Yes, directly using `.Found` can work, but I've run into so many instances where it hasn't that I just play it safe and advise the same...